# How to use Assets in Moduls in fuelphp

Tags: fuelphp

I created one view called myview.php in my modul(Named adminpanel)
path(adminpanel\views\myview.php) in that I use following code but Assets are not load

```
    <?php 
        use Fuel\Core\Asset;
        use Fuel\Core\Session;  
    ?>

<html>
<head><title>Admin Panel</title>

    <?php Asset::js(array('jquery.js','test.js'));?>

</head>
<body>

    <?php  echo Session::get('my');?>

<input type="button" value="Call Designer Controller" >
</body>
```

here test.js and jquery.js are not work properly and I donot get any error in my browser

Comment: What is the output generated? You say you don't get an error and they don't work properly but there's a few ways this can go wrong, incorrect paths being one of them, nothing being generated being another. When you ask a question provide the info others need to help you: what's the expected output and what is the output you got?

Comment: Are jquery.js and test.js inside the correct folders? Eg public folder /assets/js and I can't check now: but you might need to print Asset

Answer (score 5):

Asset::js() returns the HTML required to load the assets as a string. 
If you don't ECHO it, nothing will happen.